# CodeIgniter encode string through uri segment?

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, I am adding a search function to the site, and had two questions.

1. How would I submit a form so that it would be sent as uri segments (like a query string)?  I did it before by submitting with post, and redirecting to a url with it in the uri segments.  But is there a better way?
2. How would I send a string (such as a search query, completely user-generated) through a uri segment?  I tried urlencode, but there were still characters that weren't allowed.  I want to keep the bulk of what the query is (so it is easily found in say history, so no base64_encode).  Thoughts? Is there a built-in function for this or something?

Thanks for any help,
Max

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Do you want to submit a GET request from PHP or do you want PHP to handle a GET request? Can you explain how the user would generate the search query? PHP is server side so it can't be "user-generated". If you could elaborate on what you're trying to do and perhaps include some example of what you've done so it's clearer.

Comment: I rephrased it as best I could, does that make sense?  If not, I'll just rewrite it.

Comment: Do you have multiple fields on your search form, or just a single search box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use JavaScript to form the URL, like this:

```
<form onsubmit="window.location.href='/search/'+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('search_query').value);return false">
    <input id="search_query" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**EDIT:** The above answer will not work because of CodeIgniter's URI filter. However, from my experience with version 1.7, if you pass more than one GET parameter, you can retrieve them using the $_REQUEST array. This will bypass the URI filter altogether. So do this:

```
<form action="/search">
    <input name="x" type="hidden" />
    <input name="q" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then use $_REQUEST['q'] to get your search query. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the config option, I'll look into it

Comment: I just did this `str_replace('%',':',rawurlencode($this->input->post('search')))` to encode, and `rawurldecode(str_replace(':','%',$this->uri->segment(2)))`  
Seems to work well enough, and only encodes special characters (so words are still searchable). And use `:` (because it is encoded with url_encode, therefore it doesn't get in the way)

Comment: @Mark Eirich, this is a good methodology.  Also the setting your are referring to on the config file option can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).  A possible alternative would be to use the Controller Method "Parameters" -- its essentially the same thing as using a query string.

Comment: Could you give an example hypervisor, I can't seem to make it work :/.  Also, I was using remap so I didn't need to specify the method (which would be redundant, `search/search`)  Thoughts?

Comment: @mazzzzz Did you get CodeIgniter's "disallowed characters" error with my code? Or are you having some other problem?

Comment: What was happening was it was decoding the string before checking for bad characters, so I just replaced the % with : so it couldn't decode them (then promptly check against my own whitelist of characters)

Comment: I decided just to suck it up and deal with it, but you were the only one talking about codeigniter, and I borrowed part of your answer.

Comment: Well, there's a secret (at least it worked in CodeIgniter 1.7) - if you pass more than one GET parameter, you can retrieve them using the $_REQUEST array. This will bypass the URI filter altogether. I'm going to edit my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Create a form using `method="get"`.
2. If setup your form as mentioned above, you won't have to worry about encoding the requests.

Example:

```
<form action="example.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**Update**: To generate the form the "CodeIgniter" way:

```
echo form_open('email/send', array('method' => 'get'));
```

Comment: I was talking specifically about codeigniter (which doesn't allow GET in its standard setup), and said uri segment, not query string

Comment: @mazzzzz - I've updated my answer to include the "CodeIgniter" way of doing it.

Comment: You haven't used codeigniter.  Instead of query strings (example "?q=some%20stuff") it uses uri segments (example "search.php/q/some-stuff").  You can't use get with codeigniter with out tweaking conventions that shouldn't (imo) be tweaked.  Otherwise using GET would work.

Comment: @mazzzzz - I completely misunderstood your question. I was thrown off by the use of the word "GET" which was part of your original question. I use CodeIgniter every day but I just didn't clue in you meant URL segments. For something like a search form, segments might not be ideal, especially given the fact that punctuation, spaces and symbols aren't really going to work. Any reason why you'd want to do it that way rather than just a POST?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use something like

```
index.php?c=search&m=search&q=wow
```

instead of CI's default URI Segments

you have to enable query strings .
you can do it by changing some configuration in

```
 application/config.php
```

find

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

and change it to

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Then you will be able to use query strings .

but mots CI people prefer not to use query strings, I am not sure why .

Comment: I personally hate the look of query strings (plus I've added a lot of work into the traditional system (links and what not) so I would prefer not to switch at this point), I could deal with it if it were only the search query, but now if it is everything.

Comment: then just use the default URI segments :) , its way easier and looks cleaner .

Comment: That is what I want todo, the problem is that uri segments have more restrictions then query strings, and I can't think of a way to encode data (so that it is still readable) and decode it again.  Thoughts?

Comment: @mazzzzz - Like I said above, if it's a search query, you can't really do that. Even if you urlencoded all of the characters, it's going to look extremely ugly. For instance "It's just an example!" would turn into http://example.com/search/It's%20just%20an%20example!. You could split the words into segments but you'd have to loose the symbols, punctuation and some other characters which would make it impossible to turn the segments back into the original search query. The urls in such case would look much better (i.e. http://example.com/search/its/just/an/example). You should use POST.